# From two joins with different relationships

Tags: mysql

On my php page I want to display a table with: Voyage Name, Start Date, total distance travelled, Boat name, Captain, Crew

```
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_boatinglog |
+----------------------+
| boat                 |
| crew                 |
| vday                 |
| voyage               |
| voyage_crew          |
+----------------------+
```

I've got this far:

```
SELECT
    v.*,
    MIN(DATE_FORMAT(d.vdaydate, '%M %e, %Y')) AS vdaydate,
    SUM(d.vdaydistance) AS vdaydistance,
    boat.boatname
FROM
    voyage v
        JOIN
    vday d ON d.idvoyage = v.idvoyage
    INNER JOIN boat ON v.idboat = boat.idboat
GROUP BY v.idvoyage , v.voyagename
```

...will give me a list of the voyages with the start date from the vday table

```
SELECT v.*, c.crewname, vc.captain
FROM voyage v
     INNER JOIN
    voyage_crew vc ON vc.idvoyage = v.idvoyage
        INNER JOIN
    crew c ON vc.idcrew = c.idcrew
```

...will give me a list of crew with a "y" for the captain.

But I have no idea how to combine these two. Should I try to do it in a MySQL statement? Or some sort of loop in PHP?

```
VOYAGE
idvoyage | PRI 
voyagename
voyagearea
idboat 

VDAY
idvday | PRI
vdaydate
vdaynotes
vdaydistance
vdaystartlocation
vdayfinishlocation
idvoyage

BOAT
idboat | PRI
boatname
boattype
boatlength
boatmodel
boatyear
boatcharterco

CREW
idcrew | PRI
crewname
crewcert

VOYAGE_CREW
idvoyage | PRI 
idcrew | PRI
captain | varchar(2)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL is a touch confusing, but this might work, or something similar to this should work. Basically you need to join the two queries with the `idvoyage`

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        v.*,
        MIN(DATE_FORMAT(d.vdaydate, '%M %e, %Y')) AS vdaydate,
        SUM(d.vdaydistance) AS vdaydistance,
        boat.boatname
    FROM
        voyage v
            JOIN
        vday d ON d.idvoyage = v.idvoyage
        INNER JOIN boat ON v.idboat = boat.idboat
    GROUP BY v.idvoyage , v.voyagename
)
AS a # this table name can be anything
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT v.*, c.crewname, vc.captain
    FROM voyage v
         INNER JOIN
        voyage_crew vc ON vc.idvoyage = v.idvoyage
            INNER JOIN
        crew c ON vc.idcrew = c.idcrew
)
AS b # this table name can be anything
USING (idvoyage)
# alternately, instead of the above line with "USING", you could try:
# ON (a.idvoyage = b.idvoyage)
```

The main idea here is that you're keeping both queries exactly as-is, and just adding a big JOIN around each.

Comment: Thanks. That got me half the way there. I realize now the actual question is how do I get: yoyage name, captain, crew 1, crew 2 etc. So it occurs to me I have to go at it from the crew database and try and pull in the vday info somehow.

Comment: Ah, `SELECT v.idvoyage, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.crewname SEPARATOR ', ')` can get me what I need.